# sha256 cripted communication between client and server, using javascript, ajax and java

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, sha256

I realized a form in html, the password is sent to a servlet using a post method. In this way, data are not encripted, so I would like convert my password in sha256 before send it to a servlet.

Can I do this using javascript code?

Comment: You could use https

Comment: is it possible without https?

Comment: if you encrypt it with SHA in your JS code, everyone can see it in your JS, so the encryption is pointless from the client side. If you want to avoid man in the middle problems, https is actually the way, yes

Comment: What would you actually do with a SHA256 encrypted password at the server ..? I can't imagine any use for encryption in the context of sending  passwords to a server. You're aware, SHA256 is a "one-way ticket"?

Comment: Use HTTPS. This approach is insufficient without HTTPS and redundant with it. Also, static hashes (where x1 -> y1 every time) are a bad choice for password storage even on the server, because they are subject to dictionary attacks. You want a salted algorithm. A quick Google lead me here: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm